# Editing tags inside a table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the links in the table. not working for double quotes.
I want to take data from table and print it into textarea object. Here I want to delete some of the a tags and delete some of the links.

```js
var string = $('.table').html();
var replaceArray = ['remove', '"'];
var replaceArrayValue = ['', ''];
var finalAns = string;
for (var i = replaceArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  finalAns = finalAns.replace(RegExp("\\b" + replaceArray[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/gi, '\\$&') + "\\b", "g"), replaceArrayValue[i]);
}

$('textarea[name=data]').text(finalAns);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>
      1.2
      <a href="test.html" class="not-remove">Test</a> will be edited Test not link
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="test1.html" class="remove">Info</a> // will be deleted 2
    </td>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <a href="test2.html" class="remove">Test1</a> // will be deleted 3.1
    </td>
    <td>3.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<textarea name="data"></textarea>

<a onclick="Function()" href="javascript:;">Send</a>
```

Comment: `\b` won't work around `"`. A word boundary is when a word character is next to a non-word character. But in `href="test.html"`, `=` and `"` are both non-word characters, so `\b` won't match before `=`.

Comment: `$(".table .remove").remove()`

Comment: I'm trying to delete after enclosing variable not in design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this with regular expressions, create a copy of the DOM and modify that using DOM or jQuery methods.

```js
var copy = $('<div>', {
  html: $(".table").clone()
});
copy.find(".remove").remove();
// Replace other links with their contents
copy.find("a").replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).contents();
});

$('textarea[name=data]').text(copy.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>
      1.2
      <a href="test.html" class="not-remove">Test</a> will be edited Test not link
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="test1.html" class="remove">Info</a> // will be deleted 2
    </td>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <a href="test2.html" class="remove">Test1</a> // will be deleted 3.1
    </td>
    <td>3.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<textarea name="data"></textarea>

<a onclick="Function()" href="javascript:;">Send</a>
```

Comment: <a href="test.html" class="not-remove">Test</a> element
How can I change it to "Test" only.

Comment: I've added that to the answer, using `replaceWith()`